# Onselect needed for a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where, on select of an option in select drop down, the form should submit.

For that I have written a Jquery function

```
function xxx(val) {
 $("#form").submit();}
```

And the tag is as follows

```
 <input type="text" name="xxx_txt"  id="id_xxx" title="xxx" placeholder="xxx" value="$!{query}"  ">
```

And I am populating my text field dynamically with values

```
$("#id_xxx").autocomplete({
        source: sourcedata,
        minLength: 1
    })
```

But on select, nothing happens because, the field is not a select dropdown, but a normal text field , to which values are assigned, thus making it a select dropdown.

Basically I am writing a search function similar to google, where the search triggers , on a selection.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: you want to submit form when your `input` got populated by `autocomplete` value?

Comment: Same as in Google...

Comment: I am writing a search function similar to google, where the search triggers , on a selection.

Comment: Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

try `onChange` event on your `input` element

```
$("input#id_xxx").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() !== ""){
    $("#form").submit();
  }
});
```

> This will trigger when input element lost focus

for every change on input element:

```
$("input#id_xxx").on("input", function(){
      if($(this).val() !== ""){
        $("#form").submit();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Nothing happens.  here is what I did....$("#id_searchbox").change(function(){
console.log("hell"); 
 if($(this).val() !== ""){
    $("#id_form").submit();
  }
});  also .. here is what I again did....$("input#id_searchbox").change(function(){
console.log("hell"); 
 if($(this).val() !== ""){
    $("#id_form").submit();
  }
});